# How to change work address in Google Maps, if "My Places" option is not available?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps shows an incorrect address for my work. I'd like to change it. Google Help [tells me](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3273402) to use `My Places` option from main Google Maps menu, but I don't have such option on my PC:

[image]

Is it available only for mobiles? If so, how can I change my home or work address using PC?

Comment: It may not be available in Poland.

Answer (score 4):

If I type `work` into the search box on Google Maps, before I even hit enter, my work address is displayed in a drop-down with a nice big **EDIT** link next to it.

[image: search results]

According to [this page at Google Maps support](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3093979) searching "home" or "work" in Maps won't work in Maps "Lite mode".

It seems that the Google documentation hasn't kept up with the changes to the apps.

It's also possible that this functionality is not available in your country.

Comment: Just voting up. I'll consider accepting later. As per your comment to my question, this solution seems to be not working in Poland. Consider adding this fact to your answer, as this functionality may also be not available in other countries. I don't know, if my Google Maps works in lite or normal mode, because I don't have lightning bold as well to click it. Maybe it is not available in Poland as well, meh (the whole idea of limiting certain things in Google Maps to certain countries sounds like craziness to me)! Anyway, when I type `home` or `work` in search box, all I see is some garbage.